# Count back the week numbers based on user input (not current week number)

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a logic in PHP that returns the week number of 4 week before a given week number instead of the current weeknumber. The input for the given week number is $argv[1] because the script is executed CLI.

```
$FOURWEEKSAGO = date("W", strtotime("-4 week"));
```

Above example is with the current timestamp but i'm trying to do the same with the following. The example below doesn't work but it illustrates what I want to do.

```
$FOURWEEKSAGO = $argv[1], strtotime("-4 week");
```

The functionality must ensure that when its week 2 it will count back and results in 51 (4 week earlier)

A little help would be appreciated

Comment: you can't correctly decide the week number without considering the year as well. `date('W')` is "ISO-8601 week number". and "An ISO week-numbering year (also called ISO year informally) has 52 or 53 full weeks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `$inputWeek` be the numerical input value and `$week` the numerical resulting week.

If last year wasn't a leap-year:

```
$week = ($inputWeek + 48) % 52
```

If last year was a leap-year:

```
$week = ($inputWeek + 49) % 53
```

In order to decide whether last year was a leap-year, I assume that you can use:

```
if ((date("Y") - 2017) % 4 == 0)
```

...since 2017 is a "year-after-a-leap-year", and so every 4th year from that one is.

As pointed out in the comments, the code will get `0` if the input is `4`, which can be fixed using an `if`-statement. Note though that it's important to distinguish if week 0 is identical to week 53 or week 52. All in all:

```
if ((date("Y") - 2017) % 4 == 0) 
{
    $week = ($inputWeek + 49) % 53;
    if ($week == 0) $week = 53;
}
else 
{
    $week = ($inputWeek + 48) % 52;
    if ($week == 0) $week = 52;
}
```

Comment: now the question remains, how will OP decide on the leap-year ;)

Comment: and related to "If last year was"... why does last year matter and not the current one? if given week number is 15, returned will be 11. So it only matters when given week < 4

Comment: Alex Tartan Thanks for pointing that out! Well, you're right that it only matters if < 4, but in order to simplify the code, I just made it matter for all weeks instead. I suppose you can solve the problem in many ways, but either way you will have to use a if-clause somewhere.

Comment: Thanks @max but it doesnt seem to work. Week contains -1 

https://pastebin.com/ATq2f24j

$ php testdate.php 3
\n
output -1`

Comment: RvdM What's inside your `$argv[1]`? Right now, I assumed that it's a number like `11`.

Comment: Max: 3 and changed your + 48 to - 4. With numbers like >4 it works fine

Comment: +RvdM It has to be `+48`, because otherwise the modulo thing won't work. PHP treats modulo weirdly when it deals with negative numbers (I think it just ignores it). Try changing it back. (That is sort of the trick with my code, to use + instead of -. It should have a working effect though, because we still take mod 52 or mod 53 afterwards, putting the number back into its proper range!)

Comment: Ah yes I see. I misunderstood your logic. However 52 is shown as 0. I can simple fix this with an if statement

Comment: Should input year in your example be the current year or the last year?

Comment: RvdM It's the year that the user inputs in your code (`argv[1]`)

Comment: I'm confused. argv[1] is a week number.

Comment: RvdM Replace `$inputYear` with `$argv[1]` in my code.

Comment: Done this seems to work. InputYear suggested a yearnumber was required.

Comment: Small correction in the if statement. Twice it states 53 which needs to be changed to 52

Comment: RvdM Great! And you're right, only one should be 53. Changing that. And I meant to type `$inputWeek`... As you can tell, I'm a bit tired.

Comment: Thanks Max. Great help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148339/discussion-between-max-and-rvdm).